# Jquery animate only clicked one

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

How I can animate only the button which I click, not all of them.

I have the same "Copy" icon in every row and if I click one button, then all buttons wobble.

I want it to animate only that one that I click.

I don't want use a foreach loop to multiply code because then it makes website lag.

My JSFiddle:

```js
(function () {
  $('.btnn').click(function () {
    $('.btnn').addClass('pending');
    return setTimeout(function () {
      return $('.btnn').removeClass('pending');
    }, 1350);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
.btnn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
.btnn svg {
  fill: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.btnn svg path {
  stroke: #969696;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: stroke 0.3s ease;
}
.btnn .circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 3px solid #969696;
  transition: border 0.4s ease;
}
.btnn:hover .circle {
  border-color: #86367e;
}
.btnn:hover svg path {
  stroke: #86367e;
}
.btnn:active svg {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
.btnn.pending .circle {
  border-color: #743c6e;
  animation: animC 0.3s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.btnn.pending svg {
  animation: animS 0.4s ease-in;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.btnn.pending svg path {
  stroke: #743c6e;
}

@keyframes animS {
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
@keyframes animC {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(6px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reference to the button clicked instead of the CSS class name in the click function.

```js
(function () {
  $('.btnn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('pending');
    return setTimeout(function () {
      return $('.btnn').removeClass('pending');
    }, 1350);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
.btnn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
.btnn svg {
  fill: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.btnn svg path {
  stroke: #969696;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: stroke 0.3s ease;
}
.btnn .circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 3px solid #969696;
  transition: border 0.4s ease;
}
.btnn:hover .circle {
  border-color: #86367e;
}
.btnn:hover svg path {
  stroke: #86367e;
}
.btnn:active svg {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
.btnn.pending .circle {
  border-color: #743c6e;
  animation: animC 0.3s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.btnn.pending svg {
  animation: animS 0.4s ease-in;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.btnn.pending svg path {
  stroke: #743c6e;
}

@keyframes animS {
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
@keyframes animC {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(6px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function () {
  $('.btnn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('pending');
    return setTimeout(function () {
      return $('.btnn').removeClass('pending');
    }, 1350);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
.btnn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
.btnn svg {
  fill: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.btnn svg path {
  stroke: #969696;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: stroke 0.3s ease;
}
.btnn .circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 3px solid #969696;
  transition: border 0.4s ease;
}
.btnn:hover .circle {
  border-color: #86367e;
}
.btnn:hover svg path {
  stroke: #86367e;
}
.btnn:active svg {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
.btnn.pending .circle {
  border-color: #743c6e;
  animation: animC 0.3s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.btnn.pending svg {
  animation: animS 0.4s ease-in;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.btnn.pending svg path {
  stroke: #743c6e;
}

@keyframes animS {
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
@keyframes animC {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(6px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="btnn" href="#">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M16.469,8.924l-2.414,2.413c-0.156,0.156-0.408,0.156-0.564,0c-0.156-0.155-0.156-0.408,0-0.563l2.414-2.414c1.175-1.175,1.175-3.087,0-4.262c-0.57-0.569-1.326-0.883-2.132-0.883s-1.562,0.313-2.132,0.883L9.227,6.511c-1.175,1.175-1.175,3.087,0,4.263c0.288,0.288,0.624,0.511,0.997,0.662c0.204,0.083,0.303,0.315,0.22,0.52c-0.171,0.422-0.643,0.17-0.52,0.22c-0.473-0.191-0.898-0.474-1.262-0.838c-1.487-1.485-1.487-3.904,0-5.391l2.414-2.413c0.72-0.72,1.678-1.117,2.696-1.117s1.976,0.396,2.696,1.117C17.955,5.02,17.955,7.438,16.469,8.924 M10.076,7.825c-0.205-0.083-0.437,0.016-0.52,0.22c-0.083,0.205,0.016,0.437,0.22,0.52c0.374,0.151,0.709,0.374,0.997,0.662c1.176,1.176,1.176,3.088,0,4.263l-2.414,2.413c-0.569,0.569-1.326,0.883-2.131,0.883s-1.562-0.313-2.132-0.883c-1.175-1.175-1.175-3.087,0-4.262L6.51,9.227c0.156-0.155,0.156-0.408,0-0.564c-0.156-0.156-0.408-0.156-0.564,0l-2.414,2.414c-1.487,1.485-1.487,3.904,0,5.391c0.72,0.72,1.678,1.116,2.696,1.116s1.976-0.396,2.696-1.116l2.414-2.413c1.487-1.486,1.487-3.905,0-5.392C10.974,8.298,10.55,8.017,10.076,7.825"></path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: i change $('.btnn').addClass('pending'); to $(this).addClass('pending'); that solve ur issues